# When I activate the form, it gives an error in my app " 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: django

When I activate the form, it gives an error in my app.
The form inside the HTML file is not called.

view:

```
def student_register(request, id):

form = RegisterlesonForm()
students = Profile.objects.get(pk=id)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterlesonForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        fs = form.save(commit=False)
        fs.student = students
        fs.member_add = request.user.id
        register = Registerleson.objects.filter(
            student=id, leson=request.POST['leson']).count()
        if register > 0:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'error')
            return redirect('register_lessone', id)
        else:
            fs.save()
            return redirect('member_index')
context = {
    'form': form,
    'students': students,
}
return render(request, 'member/register_lesson.html', context)
```

code forms:

```
class RegisterlesonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Registerleson
         fields = ['leson', 'book', 'discount']
    
         widgets = {
            'leson': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'discount': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'book': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
         }
```

html code:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ثبت</button>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: please post the complete error trace